# Why browser received nothing while curl does? (When sending HTTP header response)

Tags: java, sockets, curl

I wrote Java program that uses Sockets in order to receive the http request from the client (please NOTE: Everything happens in the localhost) and my program using the Socket library outputs the header response and the html body if GET has been chosen by the client. So let me put in an example:

I run my server at port 12345 and my source file consists of the java file and the example html file.

Client, using the web browser enters: http://localhost:12345/path-to-source/File.html

Server gets input via InputStream: GET path-to-file/File.html HTTP/1.1

So it responds via OutputStream the HTTP status (200 OK), the other fields like Content-type, content-length and then the body (html source code).

For some reason, it outputs nothing to the browser. On the other hand, when I use terminal and type:

```
curl -s -I -X GET localhost:12345/path-to-file/File.html
```

It actually displays to the terminal to the client the correct output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:12345
User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: */*
Content-Length: 18900
```

But for some reason, the **Accept** is */* event though I have expected text/html

So to be clear, my desired output is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept: text/html
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 18900
Content: .....
```

Can you look at my code and spot what am I doing wrong here? Also, I don't want to use other libraries as I am trying to understand how socket works and the low level:

```
public class WebServerMain {/** This method prints to the output stream (to the client) the necessary fields, like Content type, Content length and etc.
 It only serves GET and HEAD requests and if the file exists (200). **/

    public static void printToClient(int length,BufferedReader in, PrintWriter out) {
        String request;
        String response;
        try {
            while ((request = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(request);
                if (request.split(" ")[0].equals("Accept:")) {
                    response = request.split(" ")[1].split(",")[0];
                    out.print("Content-Type: " + response + "\r\n");
                    out.print("Content-Length: " + length + "\r\n");
                    break;

                }
            }
        } catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("Usage: java WebServerMain <document_root> <port>");
        }
    }



    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String cd = "/"+ args[0]; // This is the string that user chooses to pick the directory.
            int port;
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            int length = 0; // In order to find the length of the content.
            String request;
            String response;

            final String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            System.out.println("current dir = " + dir+cd);
            // Create a ServerSocket to listen on that port.
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            // Now enter an infinite loop, waiting for & handling connections.
            for (;;) {
                // Wait for a client to connect. The method will block;
                // when it returns the socket will be connected to the client
                Socket socket = ss.accept();
                // Get input and outputstreams to talk to the client
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

                String userInput = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(userInput);
                System.out.println("Final dir is " + dir+userInput.split(" ")[1]);
                String str;
                String content = "";
                if(!userInput.split(" ")[0].equals("GET") && !userInput.split(" ")[0].equals("HEAD")){
                    out.println("HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented");
                } // Checking, if the user chose correct options, GET or HEAD. If neither, we shall print 501 status code.
                else {
                    try {
                        BufferedReader readContent = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dir+cd+userInput.split(" ")[1]));
                        while ((str = readContent.readLine()) != null) {
                            content += str;
                        } // If the file exists, we are reading its content to the string called content. String str is a temporary string.
                        length = content.length();
                        out.println(userInput.split(" ")[2] + " 200 OK");
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
                        out.println(userInput.split(" ")[2] + " 404 Not Found");
                        out.close(); // Flush and close the output stream
                        in.close(); // Close the input stream
                        socket.close(); // Close the socket itself
                    }

                    if (userInput.split(" ")[0].equals("GET")) {
                        printToClient(length, in, out);
                        out.println(content);
                    } else if (userInput.split(" ")[0].equals("HEAD")) {
                        printToClient(length, in, out);
                    }
                }

                // Close socket, breaking the connection to the client, and
                // closing the input and output streams
                out.close(); // Flush and close the output stream
                in.close(); // Close the input stream
                socket.close(); // Close the socket itself
            } // Now loop again, waiting for the next connection
        }
        // If anything goes wrong, print an error message
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a){
            System.err.println("Usage: java WebServerMain <document_root> <port>");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the headers sent by the web browser using the developer console (right-click -> inspect and then go to the network tab). There you can see what is beeing sent.

Regarding the code you have posted I would restructure two parts:

1) In the loop, after accepting a connection, branch the reading and responding logic to a new thread.

2) Instead of scattering the in.readln() throught the code, read everything in one place and then parse it.

If you go this way, it will be easy to log the whole request you received and see if your assumptions regarding what is reaching the server are correct.

Comment: Is there a way to extract HTTP response header?

Comment: In the browser? Yes you get the two things. In that tab you get the request and response and you see the headers that have been sent as well as sthe ones received.

Comment: I am not sure what to do with it. I can see the header but I still don't know, why the page is blank.

Comment: Add an out.flush() before closing the connection to make sure nothing stays buffered. (Also do a System.out.println of content to see it actually has the contents of the file)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printToClient(...
...
                out.print("Content-Type: " + response + "\r\n");
                out.print("Content-Length: " + length + "\r\n");
                break;

public static void main(String args[]) {
...
                    printToClient(length, in, out);
                    out.println(content);
```

There seems to be no `\r\n` (i.e. empty line) at the end of the HTTP response header which is required in HTTP/1.x to signal the end of the HTTP header. This means that you send an invalid response.

Apart from that your dealing with the request looks very strange for me:

- The client is not required to send an Accept header (although at least the browsers do), yet you require one.
- For whatever reason you reflect all request headers up to and including the Accept header back to the client, even if these headers don't make any sense in the response.
- You send the status line only with `println` which ends the line with `\n` only instead the required `\r\n`.
- Your error responses (404, 501) miss the `\r\n` at the end of the header top, which is required even if no body follows.

Comment: For the accept header, I just want to obtain the information regarding the content-type, like "text/html". How can I obtain it otherwise?

Comment: Can you please clarify, regarding the "\r\n"? Did you mean for the out.println(content) or out.print("Content-Length: " + length + "\r\n");?

Comment: @AlisherKassymov: lines like `out.println(userInput.split(" ")[2] + " 200 OK");` print only a `\n` as line end not `\r\n`. As for the Accept header: Which resource is served is decided based on the URL. The server *might* use this *optional* header to decide what excatly to serve in case the same resource is available in different formats (i.e. JSON, XML,...). In no way this or other request headers need to be reflected in the response.

Comment: Oh ok. I think my code mislead you a bit. I am not trying to show the accept line to the response, I was just printing to check what Accept header contains, sorry about that, I forgot to remove it. I am just extracting the first content of the accept header which is Content-type. For some reason, curl gives me */* but browser gives me text/html. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AlisherKassymov: The Accept header is not the same as the Content-Type. With the **optional** Accept header  the client can specify what kind of content-type's it is expecting, i.e. `*/*` (everything) in case of curl and usually something like `text/html, application/xhtml+xml, .... ` for browsers if they expect a HTML resource. The Content-Type instead gives what type the resource actually is.

Comment: Ok, I got it. And for the Content-Length, am I doing it right?

Comment: @AlisherKassymov: Content-Length must be bytes and as far as I understand BufferedReader it counts characters - which might be different.